# Creating a multisite registration form that also creates a woocommerce post

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, forms

I'm pretty new to wordpress in general. I'm trying to create a multisite registration form, which will ask for details for a woocommerce product posting as well (product name, product image, product regular price).

The goal is such that new signups will complete the signup process with an already created store with one product, before adding more later.

Would appreciate any guidance for this. Thanks :)